# Flutter Hot reload change to Hot restart

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Here my problem:

```
PS C:\Android\apps\test\responsive_app> flutter run -d chrome
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...             68.7s
This app is linked to the debug service: ws://127.0.0.1:61351/yScC3RT-QDs=/ws
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61351/yScC3RT-QDs=/ws

 Running with sound null safety 

  To hot restart changes while running, press "r" or "R".       
For a more detailed help message, press "h". To quit, press "q".

An Observatory debugger and profiler on Chrome is available at: http://127.0.0.1:61351/yScC3RT-QDs=
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on Chrome is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9102?uri=http://127.0.0.1:61351/yScC3RT-QDs=
```

When I try to run my flutter something change, `To hot restart changes while running, press "r" or "R".` I don't know why this can change, before it was like this `To hot reload changes while running, press "r" or "R".` I just want my Hot reload back can someone help me. My suggestion changed because I installed DevTools. How can I fix this?